# What is the difference between Intrusive Attaching and Non-Intrusive Attaching when debugging?

Tags: debugging, debuggers, dynamic-analysis

In Core Debugger Concepts What is the difference between Intrusive Attaching  and Non-Intrusive Attaching when debugging?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

non invasive debugging has access to the process memory and can inspect state
non invasive debuggine cannot perform execution controlling options like step , breakpoints etc.
non invasive  code flow is something like this

```
OpenProcess() , SuspendThread() , ReadProcessMemory() , ResumeThread() , CloseHandle()
```

Invasive debugging receives all the debugging events in the debuggee

```
CreateProcess (.,.,.,DEBUG_XXXXX,...,); so this can wait for all the DebugEvents
```